# laravel8 and Autonomous database integration in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure in ubuntu

Tags: laravel-8, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have env file like this but i am looking to integrate laravel 5.8 version with OCI bucket and Automated Transaction processing database. OS ubuntu 20.4 LTS I am aware of yajra package but it requires instant clients. so can anyone specify the steps? my PHP version is 7.4. i want to use both the db keeping one and other options.

```
    APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

can you share the exact environment variables for this?
[image: i tried with laravel 8 but yajra package did not work so far]
thanks in advance

Comment: Not an answer, but you can [install the Oracle Instant Client](https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-instant-client.html) from the [Oracle Linux yum server](https://yum.oracle.com). In OCI, you should be able to to run `yum install oracle-instantclient-release-el7` and get the IC repo enabled. Then just run `yum install oracle-instantclient-basic`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel does not officially supports Oracle databases, but you can use a third party driver. Take a look at [Oracle DB driver for Laravel 4|5|6|7|8 via OCI8](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8).

You can take a look on this document as well, this might be useful [Oracle database connections in PHP and Laravel over Ubuntu](https://supercidadedigital.com.br/oracle-database-connections-in-php-laravel-over-ubuntu/).

Comment: hi, I need both of the options to keep open for Oracle database (ODW) as well as MySQL. can you please share the details a little more about it the .env variable so that we can use both?

Comment: `laravel-oci8` doesn't support oracle cloud's autonomous databases properly.